# Using Doctrine(odm) events to implement document versioning for MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine, doctrine-odm

I want to keep tracks of documents changes set on each update and delete. To apply this, I would like write **old document** in a "`shadow collection`". Any collection I want to keep track of it, should has a shadow collection.
I want to implement this strategy in `Doctrine ODM`.

- Which doctrine event proper for this propose?
- Can I access other Document in above event?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to leverage ODM events you should take a look at [preUpdate](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/events.html#preupdate) and [preRemove](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.io/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/events.html#preremove) or (postRemove).